# how do you apply a fucntion to only numeric fields in data frame in R (excluding headers)

Tags: r

I have a data frame this data frame:

```
    structure(list(Time = structure(1:3, .Label = c("1/13/15 12:14 PM", 
"1/13/15 13:14 PM", "1/13/15 14:14 PM"), class = "factor"), Server1 = structure(1:3, .Label = c("3", 
"5", "7"), class = "factor"), Server2 = structure(1:3, .Label = c("0", 
"1.3", "34"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("Time", "Server1", 
"Server2"), row.names = c(NA, -3L), class = "data.frame")
```

I need to globaly apply a rounding function to all data points, excluding headers and datetime formated data points:

I tried this:

```
sapply(df, function(x) round(df[,2:ncol(x)],2))
```

not working, any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried converting the non-date/time values to `numeric` values *then* rounding them?

Comment: Ha!  Mine too.  With `dput()` from SO, I generally just look at the first few rows.  Here it was `dF[1:3, ]`.  It didn't even register that I saw only two rows.

Comment: @Steven, It's ok, if you were able to see the df. This is a sample df. I am trying this df<-data.frame(sapply(df,function(x) round(x, 2))), I get this error: round not meaningful for factors

Comment: Something's up with your data you put into your question.  Regardless, the error you're getting `round not meaningful for factors` should tell you that what you're doing can't be done.  Convert the column with `as.numeric` and try again.

Comment: @Steven, when I do as.numeric, I need to exclude column1 and headings. try this: df<-data.frame(sapply(df,function(x) round(as.numeric(x[2,2:ncol(x)]),2))

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since you've got all factor columns there, you'll likely need to manually determine which ones are to be converted.  Here's a function we can use to convert factors to their original numeric values.  This uses the recommended method as described in the *Warning* section of `help(factor)`.

```
f <- function(x) as.numeric(levels(x))[x]
```

Next we can apply this function to the desired columns and round them at the same time.  In this case we want to apply `f()` to every column except the first, so we use the index `[-1]`.

```
df[-1] <- lapply(df[-1], function(x) round(f(x), 2))
df
#               Time Server1 Server2
# 1 1/13/15 12:14 PM       3     0.0
# 2 1/13/15 13:14 PM       5     1.3
# 3 1/13/15 14:14 PM       7    34.0
```

Check the resulting column classes:

```
sapply(df, class)
#     Time   Server1   Server2 
# "factor" "numeric" "numeric"
```

Answer (score 5):

If what you intend to do is round all columns that are `numeric` without manual checking in advance which columns are `numeric` and without specifying specific column numbers:

```
idx <- sapply(df, class)=="numeric"
df[, idx] <- lapply(df[, idx], round)
```

The presumption of course is that all relevant columns are already `numeric`, not `character` with digits, `factor`, etc.

Comment: I recommend using `sapply` instead of `lapply` to handle cases in which there's only 1 numeric column.

Answer (score 1):

I stole some of your data since the data you provided is all screwy.

```
x <- c("1/13/15 1:14 PM", "1/13/15 10:14 PM", "1/13/15 11:14 PM", 
       "1/13/15 12:14 PM", "1/13/15 2:14 PM")
y <- c("0%", "0.08%", "0.17%", "0.25%", "0.33%")
z <- c("0", "0.08333", "0.16667", "0.25", "0.33333")

dF <- data.frame(x, y, z)
```

Remove the `%` symbol from the values and convert to a number:

```
dF$y <- as.numeric(gsub("%", "", dF$y))
```

Convert your third column to a number and round:

```
dF$z <- round(as.numeric(as.character(dF$z)), 2)
```

#### Edited in response to your comment:

Clearly, I'm confused.  Rounding makes sense for numbers not characters.  You have to convert the columns you're interested in to numbers before you can round them.

After you've converted them to `numeric` values, just use:

```
dF[,-1] <-round(dF[,-1], 2) # The -1 excludes column 1
dF
                 x    y    z
1  1/13/15 1:14 PM 0.00 0.00
2 1/13/15 10:14 PM 0.08 0.08
3 1/13/15 11:14 PM 0.17 0.17
4 1/13/15 12:14 PM 0.25 0.25
5  1/13/15 2:14 PM 0.33 0.33
```

There is no need to be concerned that you're going to round the names of your data frame.  You won't.  But I'm fairly certain that you *must* convert your factors/characters to numbers before rounding them.  If I'm wrong, I'm sure another SO users will educate us both.

#### Edited with your new data in the original post:

When you try to round a factor, you will get an error:

```
 dF <- structure(list(Time = structure(1:3, .Label = c("1/13/15 12:14PM",
                 "1/13/15 13:14 PM", "1/13/15 14:14 PM"), class = 
                 "factor"), Server1 = structure(1:3, .Label = c("3", 
                  "5", "7"), class = "factor"), Server2 = structure(1:3, 
                  .Label = c("0", "1.3", "34"), class = "factor")), Names 
                  = c("Time", "Server1", "Server2"), row.names = c(NA, 
                  -3L), class = "data.frame")
dF[,-1] <-round(dF[,-1], 0) # The -1 excludes column 1
Error in Math.data.frame(list(Server1 = 1:3, Server2 = 1:3), 0) : 
non-numeric variable in data frame: Server1Server2
```

You *must* convert the factors to numbers before you round them, otherwise you will get the error above:

```
dF[, 2] <- as.numeric(as.character(dF[, 2]))
dF[, 3] <- as.numeric(as.character(dF[, 3]))
dF[,-1] <-round(dF[,-1], 0) # The -1 excludes column 1
dF
              Time Server1 Server2
1 1/13/15 12:14 PM       3       0
2 1/13/15 13:14 PM       5       1
3 1/13/15 14:14 PM       7      34
```

The `round()` statement does not get hung on the "headers".  But you MUST convert your factors to numbers before you can `round()` them.

Comment: I am familiar with referincing columns by $ and doing it but I was actually looking for regardles of the columns, round everthing in the data frame except for column1 and headers.

Comment: sorry this will not work either. It is readding headers, headers are factors and erroring out.

Comment: Please edit your original post and provide a functioning `dput()` of your data.